# Batch - For and Findstr with multiple criteria printed on same line

Tags: api, batch-file, for-loop, findstr

I am trying to parse some xml files and extract some data. The data pertains to the Magic The Gathering card game card data from an API. The results when I search for a card (Goblin Warchief in this example) look like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<response>
  <product>
    <idProduct>1090</idProduct>
    <idMetaproduct>2459</idMetaproduct>
    <countReprints>8</countReprints>
    <enName>Goblin Warchief</enName>
    <locName>Goblin Warchief</locName>
    <localization>
      <name>Goblin Warchief</name>
      <idLanguage>1</idLanguage>
      <languageName>English</languageName>
    </localization>
    <localization>
      <name>Chef de guerre gobelin</name>
      <idLanguage>2</idLanguage>
      <languageName>French</languageName>
    </localization>
    <localization>
      <name>Goblin-Kriegsh„uptling</name>
      <idLanguage>3</idLanguage>
      <languageName>German</languageName>
    </localization>
    <localization>
      <name>Jefe de guerra trasgo</name>
      <idLanguage>4</idLanguage>
      <languageName>Spanish</languageName>
    </localization>
    <localization>
      <name>Condottiero Goblin</name>
      <idLanguage>5</idLanguage>
      <languageName>Italian</languageName>
    </localization>
    <website>/en/Magic/Products/Singles/Scourge/Goblin-Warchief</website>
    <image>./img/items/1/SCG/1090.jpg</image>
    <gameName>Magic the Gathering</gameName>
    <categoryName>Magic Single</categoryName>
    <idGame>1</idGame>
    <number>97</number>
    <rarity>Uncommon</rarity>
    <expansionName>Scourge</expansionName>
    <expansionIcon>41</expansionIcon>
    <countArticles>1524</countArticles>
    <countFoils>41</countFoils>
    <links>
      <rel>product</rel>
      <href>/products/1090</href>
      <method>GET</method>
    </links>
  </product>
  <product>
    <idProduct>15846</idProduct>
    <idMetaproduct>2459</idMetaproduct>
    <countReprints>8</countReprints>
    <enName>Goblin Warchief (Version 1)</enName>
    <locName>Goblin Warchief (Version 1)</locName>
    <localization>
      <name>Goblin Warchief</name>
      <idLanguage>1</idLanguage>
      <languageName>English</languageName>
    </localization>
    <localization>
      <name>Chef de guerre gobelin</name>
      <idLanguage>2</idLanguage>
      <languageName>French</languageName>
    </localization>
    <localization>
      <name>Goblin-Kriegsh„uptling</name>
      <idLanguage>3</idLanguage>
      <languageName>German</languageName>
    </localization>
    <localization>
      <name>Jefe de guerra trasgo</name>
      <idLanguage>4</idLanguage>
      <languageName>Spanish</languageName>
    </localization>
    <localization>
      <name>Condottiero Goblin</name>
      <idLanguage>5</idLanguage>
      <languageName>Italian</languageName>
    </localization>
    <website>/en/Magic/Products/Singles/Friday+Night+Magic+Promos/Goblin-Warchief-Version-1</website>
    <image>./img/items/1/FNM/15846.jpg</image>
    <gameName>Magic the Gathering</gameName>
    <categoryName>Magic Single</categoryName>
    <idGame>1</idGame>
    <number>2006-05</number>
    <rarity>Rare</rarity>
    <expansionName>Friday Night Magic Promos</expansionName>
    <expansionIcon>69</expansionIcon>
    <countArticles>234</countArticles>
    <countFoils>213</countFoils>
    <links>
      <rel>product</rel>
      <href>/products/15846</href>
      <method>GET</method>
    </links>
  </product>
  <product>
    <idProduct>288444</idProduct>
    <idMetaproduct>2459</idMetaproduct>
    <countReprints>8</countReprints>
    <enName>Goblin Warchief (Version 2)</enName>
    <locName>Goblin Warchief (Version 2)</locName>
    <localization>
      <name>Goblin Warchief</name>
      <idLanguage>1</idLanguage>
      <languageName>English</languageName>
    </localization>
    <localization>
      <name>Chef de guerre gobelin</name>
      <idLanguage>2</idLanguage>
      <languageName>French</languageName>
    </localization>
    <localization>
      <name>Goblin-Kriegsh„uptling</name>
      <idLanguage>3</idLanguage>
      <languageName>German</languageName>
    </localization>
    <localization>
      <name>Jefe de guerra trasgo</name>
      <idLanguage>4</idLanguage>
      <languageName>Spanish</languageName>
    </localization>
    <localization>
      <name>Condottiero Goblin</name>
      <idLanguage>5</idLanguage>
      <languageName>Italian</languageName>
    </localization>
    <website>/en/Magic/Products/Singles/Friday+Night+Magic+Promos/Goblin-Warchief-Version-2</website>
    <image>./img/items/1/FNM/288444.jpg</image>
    <gameName>Magic the Gathering</gameName>
    <categoryName>Magic Single</categoryName>
    <idGame>1</idGame>
    <number>2016-05</number>
    <rarity>Rare</rarity>
    <expansionName>Friday Night Magic Promos</expansionName>
    <expansionIcon>69</expansionIcon>
    <countArticles>1425</countArticles>
    <countFoils>1425</countFoils>
    <links>
      <rel>product</rel>
      <href>/products/288444</href>
      <method>GET</method>
    </links>
  </product>
  <product>
    <idProduct>18797</idProduct>
    <idMetaproduct>2459</idMetaproduct>
    <countReprints>8</countReprints>
    <enName>Goblin Warchief</enName>
    <locName>Goblin Warchief</locName>
    <localization>
      <name>Goblin Warchief</name>
      <idLanguage>1</idLanguage>
      <languageName>English</languageName>
    </localization>
    <localization>
      <name>Chef de guerre gobelin</name>
      <idLanguage>2</idLanguage>
      <languageName>French</languageName>
    </localization>
    <localization>
      <name>Goblin-Kriegsh„uptling</name>
      <idLanguage>3</idLanguage>
      <languageName>German</languageName>
    </localization>
    <localization>
      <name>Jefe de guerra trasgo</name>
      <idLanguage>4</idLanguage>
      <languageName>Spanish</languageName>
    </localization>
    <localization>
      <name>Condottiero Goblin</name>
      <idLanguage>5</idLanguage>
      <languageName>Italian</languageName>
    </localization>
    <website>/en/Magic/Products/Singles/Duel+Decks%3A+Elves+vs.+Goblins/Goblin-Warchief</website>
    <image>./img/items/1/EVG/18797.jpg</image>
    <gameName>Magic the Gathering</gameName>
    <categoryName>Magic Single</categoryName>
    <idGame>1</idGame>
    <number>42</number>
    <rarity>Uncommon</rarity>
    <expansionName>Duel Decks: Elves vs. Goblins</expansionName>
    <expansionIcon>88</expansionIcon>
    <countArticles>254</countArticles>
    <countFoils>0</countFoils>
    <links>
      <rel>product</rel>
      <href>/products/18797</href>
      <method>GET</method>
    </links>
  </product>
  <product>
    <idProduct>249281</idProduct>
    <idMetaproduct>2459</idMetaproduct>
    <countReprints>8</countReprints>
    <enName>Goblin Warchief</enName>
    <locName>Goblin Warchief</locName>
    <localization>
      <name>Goblin Warchief</name>
      <idLanguage>1</idLanguage>
      <languageName>English</languageName>
    </localization>
    <localization>
      <name>Chef de guerre gobelin</name>
      <idLanguage>2</idLanguage>
      <languageName>French</languageName>
    </localization>
    <localization>
      <name>Goblin-Kriegsh„uptling</name>
      <idLanguage>3</idLanguage>
      <languageName>German</languageName>
    </localization>
    <localization>
      <name>Jefe de guerra trasgo</name>
      <idLanguage>4</idLanguage>
      <languageName>Spanish</languageName>
    </localization>
    <localization>
      <name>Condottiero Goblin</name>
      <idLanguage>5</idLanguage>
      <languageName>Italian</languageName>
    </localization>
    <website>/en/Magic/Products/Singles/WCD+2003%3A+Wolfgang+Eder/Goblin-Warchief</website>
    <image>./img/items/1/WCD34/249281.jpg</image>
    <gameName>Magic the Gathering</gameName>
    <categoryName>Magic Single</categoryName>
    <idGame>1</idGame>
    <number></number>
    <rarity>Special</rarity>
    <expansionName>WCD 2003: Wolfgang Eder</expansionName>
    <expansionIcon>87</expansionIcon>
    <countArticles>35</countArticles>
    <countFoils>0</countFoils>
    <links>
      <rel>product</rel>
      <href>/products/249281</href>
      <method>GET</method>
    </links>
  </product>
  <product>
    <idProduct>268812</idProduct>
    <idMetaproduct>2459</idMetaproduct>
    <countReprints>8</countReprints>
    <enName>Goblin Warchief</enName>
    <locName>Goblin Warchief</locName>
    <localization>
      <name>Goblin Warchief</name>
      <idLanguage>1</idLanguage>
      <languageName>English</languageName>
    </localization>
    <localization>
      <name>Chef de guerre gobelin</name>
      <idLanguage>2</idLanguage>
      <languageName>French</languageName>
    </localization>
    <localization>
      <name>Goblin-Kriegsh„uptling</name>
      <idLanguage>3</idLanguage>
      <languageName>German</languageName>
    </localization>
    <localization>
      <name>Jefe de guerra trasgo</name>
      <idLanguage>4</idLanguage>
      <languageName>Spanish</languageName>
    </localization>
    <localization>
      <name>Condottiero Goblin</name>
      <idLanguage>5</idLanguage>
      <languageName>Italian</languageName>
    </localization>
    <website>/en/Magic/Products/Singles/Duel+Decks%3A+Speed+vs.+Cunning/Goblin-Warchief</website>
    <image>./img/items/1/DDN/268812.jpg</image>
    <gameName>Magic the Gathering</gameName>
    <categoryName>Magic Single</categoryName>
    <idGame>1</idGame>
    <number>9</number>
    <rarity>Uncommon</rarity>
    <expansionName>Duel Decks: Speed vs. Cunning</expansionName>
    <expansionIcon>256</expansionIcon>
    <countArticles>1198</countArticles>
    <countFoils>0</countFoils>
    <links>
      <rel>product</rel>
      <href>/products/268812</href>
      <method>GET</method>
    </links>
  </product>
  <product>
    <idProduct>270006</idProduct>
    <idMetaproduct>2459</idMetaproduct>
    <countReprints>8</countReprints>
    <enName>Goblin Warchief</enName>
    <locName>Goblin Warchief</locName>
    <localization>
      <name>Goblin Warchief</name>
      <idLanguage>1</idLanguage>
      <languageName>English</languageName>
    </localization>
    <localization>
      <name>Chef de guerre gobelin</name>
      <idLanguage>2</idLanguage>
      <languageName>French</languageName>
    </localization>
    <localization>
      <name>Goblin-Kriegsh„uptling</name>
      <idLanguage>3</idLanguage>
      <languageName>German</languageName>
    </localization>
    <localization>
      <name>Jefe de guerra trasgo</name>
      <idLanguage>4</idLanguage>
      <languageName>Spanish</languageName>
    </localization>
    <localization>
      <name>Condottiero Goblin</name>
      <idLanguage>5</idLanguage>
      <languageName>Italian</languageName>
    </localization>
    <website>/en/Magic/Products/Singles/Duel+Decks%3A+Anthology/Goblin-Warchief</website>
    <image>./img/items/1/DD3/270006.jpg</image>
    <gameName>Magic the Gathering</gameName>
    <categoryName>Magic Single</categoryName>
    <idGame>1</idGame>
    <number>2042</number>
    <rarity>Uncommon</rarity>
    <expansionName>Duel Decks: Anthology</expansionName>
    <expansionIcon>259</expansionIcon>
    <countArticles>230</countArticles>
    <countFoils>0</countFoils>
    <links>
      <rel>product</rel>
      <href>/products/270006</href>
      <method>GET</method>
    </links>
  </product>
  <product>
    <idProduct>319794</idProduct>
    <idMetaproduct>2459</idMetaproduct>
    <countReprints>8</countReprints>
    <enName>Goblin Warchief</enName>
    <locName>Goblin Warchief</locName>
    <localization>
      <name>Goblin Warchief</name>
      <idLanguage>1</idLanguage>
      <languageName>English</languageName>
    </localization>
    <localization>
      <name>Chef de guerre gobelin</name>
      <idLanguage>2</idLanguage>
      <languageName>French</languageName>
    </localization>
    <localization>
      <name>Goblin-Kriegsh„uptling</name>
      <idLanguage>3</idLanguage>
      <languageName>German</languageName>
    </localization>
    <localization>
      <name>Jefe de guerra trasgo</name>
      <idLanguage>4</idLanguage>
      <languageName>Spanish</languageName>
    </localization>
    <localization>
      <name>Condottiero Goblin</name>
      <idLanguage>5</idLanguage>
      <languageName>Italian</languageName>
    </localization>
    <website>/en/Magic/Products/Singles/Dominaria/Goblin-Warchief</website>
    <image>./img/items/1/DOM/319794.jpg</image>
    <gameName>Magic the Gathering</gameName>
    <categoryName>Magic Single</categoryName>
    <idGame>1</idGame>
    <number>130</number>
    <rarity>Uncommon</rarity>
    <expansionName>Dominaria</expansionName>
    <expansionIcon>419</expansionIcon>
    <countArticles>7370</countArticles>
    <countFoils>221</countFoils>
    <links>
      <rel>product</rel>
      <href>/products/319794</href>
      <method>GET</method>
    </links>
  </product>
  <links>
    <rel>self</rel>
    <href>/products/find?search=Goblin%20Warchief&amp;exact=true&amp;idGame=1&amp;idLanguage=1</href>
    <method>GET</method>
  </links>
</response>
```

So, as you can see, there are often multiple results for any given card search.

Now, what I am interested in doing is printing to a seperate file the  and  fields for each product, on the same line. So like this:

```
Goblin Warchief_Scourge
Goblin Warchief (Version 1)_Friday Night Magic Promos
Goblin Warchief (Version 2)_Friday Night Magic Promos
etc
```

I'd prefer to do this in batch, and the best I have managed to do so far is to simply print the enName and expansionName fields separately, with this:

```
@echo off

if exist searchResultFiltered.xml del searchResultFiltered.xml

rem The card name is passed in from the command line
set cardname=%~1

rem This uses an outside application to interface the API
mkm get "products/find?search=%cardname%&exact=true&idGame=1&idLanguage=1" > searchResult.xml

for /f "tokens=3 delims=<>" %%j in ('findstr "enName expansionName" "searchResult.xml"') do >> searchResultFiltered.xml echo %%j
```

This gives the output like this:

```
Goblin Warchief
Scourge
Goblin Warchief (Version 1)
Friday Night Magic Promos
Goblin Warchief (Version 2)
Friday Night Magic Promos
etc...
```

Can anyone help me get the line "pairs" onto the same line with a delimiter in-between please? I'd appreciate any help. I don't know if there's a way of doing it neatly with for and findstr, or if I need to print them to a new file or something.

Thanks!

Comment: Let me strongly recommend to use a language (like [tag:powershell], for instance) that natively supports XML, because when treating such as normal text (as you do with a [tag:batch-file]) you will get into trouble when the data does not look exactly like you expect...

Comment: I appreciate the advice, but this is for a simple hobby project that doesn't need to be too resilient, and I'm already familiar with Batch. I'll look into Powershell for a later revision though :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 set "flag="
 for /f "tokens=3 delims=<>" %%j in ('findstr "enName expansionName" "searchResult.xml"') do (
 if defined flag (
  >> searchResultFiltered.xml call echo %%flag%% %%j&set "flag="
 ) else (set "flag=%%j")
 )
```

`flag` is initialised to *nothing*.

The first item passing the `findstr` filter sees `flag` as not-defined, so `set`s (and hence *defines*) `flag` to the required text.

The next item through the gate now sees `flag` as *defined* hence `echo`es its value + the current line's value in a subshell; then clears `flag`.

Rinse and repeat.

For examples about the `call echo %%var%%` method to display the *current* value of `var`, see many articles on SO about `delayed expansion`.